# React-Native info command throwing error is it related to Babel? How to fix that?

Tags: macos, react-native, babeljs

`react-native -v` gives me this:

> ```
> react-native-cli: 2.0.1
> react-native: 0.57.1
> ```

When I run any other command like `react-native info` or `react-native run-android` keep giving me below error:

> ```
> function getCliConfig(){var cliArgs,config,expoAssetPluginPath;return regeneratorRuntime.async(function getCliConfig$(_context){while(1){switch(_context.prev=_context.next){case 0:
>                                                                ^
>
> ReferenceError: regeneratorRuntime is not defined
>     at getCliConfig (/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/juices/node_modules/react-native/local-cli/core/index.js:128:64)
>     at Object.<anonymous> (/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/juices/node_modules/react-native/local-cli/core/index.js:181:30)
>     at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:654:30)
>     at Module._compile (/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/juices/node_modules/pirates/lib/index.js:83:24)
>     at Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:665:10)
>     at Object.newLoader [as .js] (/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/juices/node_modules/pirates/lib/index.js:88:7)
>     at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:566:32)
>     at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:506:12)
>     at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:498:3)
>     at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:598:17)
> ```

Answer (score 0):

Actually this issue related to react-native version, For now, Expo supporting till version 0.55.4. Please downgrade react-native version and try again and I hope it will work.

Expo Documentation (Supported Versions):-
https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/sdk/#sdk-version

Try this for downgrade your react-native version:-

```
npm install react-native@0.55.4
```